# file_put_contents empties when large image data uri is sent

Tags: javascript, php, file

Hi I use `file_put_contents()` in PHP to write/edit HTML contents of a remote HTML file. This works fine when I'm sending just HTML syntax/tags. and it also works fine while sending small size data uri images (eg:- `<img src="data: image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg......."/>`) inside the code.

But when the image size is more than 100kb. The remote HTML page becomes empty.

May I know whats the reason for this? Is there a size limit while writing `files in file_put_contents()`?

Following is my code for writing the HTML file:

```
$info = file_get_contents("path/to/page/$page");

//here i'm searching for <!-- container begin --> comment jsut to replace them with the posted data
 $replaced = preg_replace('|(<!\-\- container begin \-\->.*<!\-\- container end \-\->)|isU','<!-- container begin -->'. (string) $_POST['content'].'<!-- container end -->', $info);

 //after replacing i'm insering/replacing the whole code in the html file 
 file_put_contents("path/to/page/$page", $replaced);
```

the `$_POST['content']` is sent through ajax.

edit:-  when i send a large file for the first time it works good. but when i send the same data again, it is again empty.

Comment: What do you mean by "The remote HTML page becomes empty".  Are you using a stream with file_put_contents or do you mean the file you are writing is empty?  Have you confirmed the issue is with file_put_contents and not that `$replaced` is empty?

Comment: well actually the `$replaced` is empty. "The remote HTML page becomes empty" by that i mean the whole content/code in the html page are erased.

Comment: If `$replaced` is empty, then it isn't an issue with file_put_contents..

Comment: oh, so where will be the problem?? and i also noticed another thing. when i send a large file for the first time it works good. but when i send the same data again, it is again empty.

Comment: Why is this tagged JavaScript?

Comment: because i'm using ajax to send the data.

Comment: I think you need to add some checks and learn how to debug.  Check  that `$info` isn't empty.  During development, maybe you should print this out to make sure it is meeting your expectations.  If `$replaced` is empty, don't run file_put_contents and throw an exception or error and so on..

Comment: i'm sure the `$info` is not empty. i think there is some problem in `preg_replace()` because both `$info` and `$_POST['content']` are not empty. but anyway i just used direct linking...i don't seem to find a solution for this , atleast now.